# IDA Pro ignores condition in breakpoint

Tags: ida, disassembly, debugging, gdb, breakpoint

[image: Screenshot of the breakpoint options]

Look at the condition. It is supposed to break only when the R2 is 40, but it breaks in any call to this instruction. I'm using IDA Pro 7.2.181105, debugging with Remote GDB Debugger, an ARMv4T code. I'm completely beginner with IDA Pro.

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry friend, I did no found. Upvote the question so maybe someone answer it on the future. I give up on this project. Now instead I use GHIDRA btw.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the Actions from "Trace" to "Break" When the condition is true the action will execute.

[image]

Comment: Still the same issue changing breakpoint from trace to break.

Comment: Do you have another idea?

Comment: are you using gdbserver, qemu, openOCD or something else as the "Gdb stub" ? I would check with gdb command you can set the conditional breakpoint i.e. break <location> if $r2 == 40.

Comment: In the `output window`, I select `GDB` and type `break <location> if $r2 == 40` (changing <location> to the adress) and hit enter. The error is: `<error sending command to monitor>`. I'm using mGBA to debug a GBA Advance game